# Statistics Problems and Solutions Second Edition 2B.4

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, normal-distribution

$\color{white}{\require{\cancel}{3}}$

So I was again recently looking through [Statistics Problems and Solutions Second Edition by Bassett et al., 1986](https://bayanbox.ir/view/515725738597127443/STATISTICS-problems-and-solutions.pdf) when I ran into this interesting problem:

> $2$B.$4\quad$The number of matches in a box
>
> A manufacturer claims that boxes contain, on average, $49$ matches. On checking output over a substantial period, the manager finds that $3$% of boxes contain fewer than $46$ but $\quad25$% contain $51$ or more. Making reasonable assumptions, calculate the mean and standard deviation of the number of matches per box. Do you feel like the manufacturer's claim is plausible?

**What I know from this question**

---

1. Defining the numbers of matches in a box as $x$, we know that $$\operatorname{avg}(x\in\mathbb{B})=49\,\text{where }\mathbb{B}\text{ is any one box.}$$
2. The probability of there being less than $46$ matches in any one box $\mathbb{B}$ can be calculated as $\operatorname{Pr}(x\lt46)=0.03$
3. The probability of there being more than or equal to $51$ matches in any given box $\mathbb{B}$ can be calculated as $$\operatorname{Pr}(x\geq51)=0.25$$

**My attempt to solve it**

---

Let $\mu$ denote the mean and $\sigma$ define the mean and standard deviation. Now,$$\Phi\left(\frac{\frac{91}{2}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=0.03\quad\text{and}
\quad1-\Phi\left(\frac{\frac{101}{2}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=0.25$$Since I know that on standard tables,$$\Phi(k_1)=0.03\text{ where }k_1\approx-1.88\text{ and }\Phi(k_2)=0.75\text{ where }k_2\approx0.67$$Solving the $2$-system equation$$\mu-1.88\sigma=45.5\text{ and }\mu+0.67\sigma=50.5$$gets us$$\mu\approx49.186$$$$\text{and}$$$$\sigma\approx1.961$$$$\text{ meaning that it would be the correct decision to believe the manufacturer's claim.}$$**My question**

---

Is my solution correct, or what steps would I need to take to attain the correct solution more easily, as well as any steps that might make it easier to solve?

**To clarify**

---

1. This is different from my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4683080/statistics-problems-and-solutions-second-edition-2a-7-part-iii).
2. I am absolutely sorry if this is a short/trivial question.
3. Sorry if I accidently skipped any steps that would make it easier to solve/would get me the correct answer.
4. Sorry if my tags aren't correct, they most likely are but still.

Comment: Also sorry about the random edit ~11min ago (at the time of posting this comment) I just noticed some random errors that I had to fix and I absolutely hate it for not catching that beforehand

Comment: I agree with your solution.  You should mention that you are assuming the number of matches per box is approximately Normal (it can't really be Normal because the number of matches is always an integer)  and that you have adjusted for continuity by using $45.5$ and $50.5$ as your bounds.

Comment: Also, in assessing the manufacurer's claim, you should compute the difference between the claimed mean and the true mean in terms of the number of *standard deviations*.